# Probability of having to walk: N people on a motorcycle trip

Tags: probability

I'm relatively new to probabilities in mathematics and just had a thought, which I couldn't map directly to examples. (maybe it's Marbles in a Bag?).

Problem:
Case 1: 2 People on a motorcycle trip. Probability of a moto to break say is 0.5. Each has his own bike, which has 2 seats (1 spare).

What's the probability for each that he has to walk home? How does is look if there are 3 people on total of 6 seats?

Thanks for your ideas!

UPDATE: I asked a friend for help and got that formula for 3 bikes:
[image of formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrhwX.gif)

(Possibilities 3 of 3 + Possibilities 2 of 3) / Amount of scenarios

((3 choose 3)         + (3 choose 2))        / 2^3 = 0.5

Does that make sense?